# Passing parameter from feature file to another feature file

Tags: parameter-passing, karate, feature-file

I do have a feature file which is retrieving a data from a query and when calling another feature file it will pass the query result as well as a statement values.

statement parameter:

1. Source i.e. Provider
2. target i.e. Tenant

query response:

1. Qname i.e. defaultDirectory

These three values have to be passed to another feature file as POST statements. The POST statement will look like at the end:

```
And request {"statements": [{"statement": "match(p:Provider)--(t:Tenant{Name:'defaultDirectory'}) return p"}]}
When method POST
```

I am lost on how to declare these values in feature file 1 and how to do the statement with these parameters.

Comment: besides the linked question, please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files

Comment: I am getting these values from feature file 1 to feature file 2. I thought maybe there is a more elegant way rather doing

* def result = call read('classpath:GetECDMTenantParent.feature') { "Parent": "#(Parent)", "Child": "#(Child)" , QName"": "#(QName)"}

Comment: any variable that exists in feature 1 will automatically be available in 2. you DON'T need to always use arguments. try doing a `def` in feature 1 and see. and all of this is explained in the docs